# Razer 14 (2023) no audio in 23.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

I just recently purchased a new Razer 14 (2023) laptop and installed Ubuntu 23.04 on it. The SSD is partitioned in half and dual-boots Windows 11. Windows 11 audio works flawlessly (so I know it isn't a hardware issue). My audio is detected, but there is no output from the speakers (no popping or static, just nothing).

Using "PulseAudio", it shows a 'Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Speaker + Headphones', the port is set to 'Speaker' and there is still no audio output. I have tried several different types of configuration within the application and nothing has worked.

I also attempted to use 'HDAJackRetask' in order to override output to force audio, and it also did not work.

`aplay -l` 's output looks like the following:

```
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I also used PipeWire to try and further diagnose it. This is the output of `pw-cli list-objects | grep node.name`

```
        node.name = "Dummy-Driver"
        node.name = "Freewheel-Driver"
        node.name = "Midi-Bridge"
        node.name = "v4l2_input.pci-0000_65_00.4-usb-0_1_1.0"
        node.name = "v4l2_input.pci-0000_65_00.4-usb-0_1_1.2"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_65_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__sink"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_65_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__source"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_65_00.6.HiFi__hw_acp63__source"
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction for how to get the audio working properly? Everything else (hardware-wise) seems to be working just fine. I found some "similar" questions on this board, but most people said simply rebooting randomly had their audio start working (usually from a cold boot rather than a restart). At no point has the audio worked for me in Ubuntu, but again, works flawlessly in Windows.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you append the output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`?

Comment: Won't help, but [here is the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1851518). So you did everything right, but Realtek doesn't care about Linux..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying out uninstalling Pulseaudio and only using PipeWire? It's a solution offered [here, specifically on the Lubuntu discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-23-04-now-uses-pipewire-info-you-should-know-call-for-testing/3907), but specifically for version 23.04.

I know you are using Ubuntu, but it came to mind. Perhaps it could help, or at least give you something to try.